# Unable to scrape etherscan transaction urls - cloudflare protection

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, etherscan

Code to scrape etherscan transaction block id

```
def block_chain_explorer_block_id(url):
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    tags = soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class':'col-md-9'}) 
    print(soup.findAll('a'))

block_chain_explorer_block_id(https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4529e9f79139edab871a699df455e57101cca90574e435da89db457df4885c54)
```

Output getting :

```
[<a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a>]
```

I am getting above output `polygonscan` works fine. etherscan works fine.
any idea how to make it work ?

Comment: It is scrape, scraping, scraper - scrap is something completely different

Comment: I had issues too, did you get anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Adding some headers to the request, to show up you might be a "*browser*" can provide momentary relief, but it is far from bulletproof.

You should also consider how often and at what speed you visit which of the target pages.

Use of rotating proxies is also a common approach.

**Note** *There is no magic formula for this, as Cloudflare is constantly adapting its methods for detecting bot traffic. - Using an api as mentioned by @Speedlulu would be the best approach*

#### Example

Added `user agent` as one of the headers and also changed `findAll()` to `find_all()` cause this is the syntax you should use in new code.

```
import requests
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}

def block_chain_explorer_block_id(url):
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    tags = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'class':'col-md-9'}) 
    print(soup.find_all('a'))

block_chain_explorer_block_id('https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4529e9f79139edab871a699df455e57101cca90574e435da89db457df4885c54')
```

Comment: this working in my macbook but not working inside ubuntu server

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan has an API (with a Free plan).

You should use it instead of trying to scrape it, here's the doc for Transactions : https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/stats

Comment: the api is very limited